# Logger not able to write when being called in other functions

Tags: go

Note: Newbie for golang language

Here is the sample program hello.go I wrote to check the behavior and I am seeing the issue where I don't see anything being written by Logger in any functions other than init().

```
package main  
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"
    "log"
)  
var (
  testLogger *log.Logger
)  
func init() {
    test_log := "/tmp/t1.log"
    fmt.Printf("Logs are saved to %v\n", test_log)
    f, err := os.OpenFile(test_log, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR  Can't create log file! Reason: %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    multiWriter := io.MultiWriter(f)
    testLogger = log.New(multiWriter, "", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    testLogger.Printf("in init..")
}  
func main() {
    pretest()
    test()
    testLogger.Printf("Back to main ... ")
}  
func pretest() {
    testLogger.Printf("In pretest ... ")
}  
func test() {
  testLogger.Printf("in test..")    
}
```

Here is the output and content of the file being written to:

➜  ./hello
Logs are saved to /tmp/t1.log
➜  cat /tmp/t1.log
2018/06/28 11:23:25 hello.go:27: in init..

AFAIK, The testLogger being shared in the same package should be accessible by each function and able to being used. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong? Am I missing anything in the code? Please provide any pointer or reference on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
defer f.Close()
```

You are doing that `defer` in the `init` function, meaning that the file will be closed as soon as the `init` function finishes.

Since the `init` function runs before `main`, the file will be closed already when you try to write from all your other functions.

Move that `defer` to the main function so that it is closed when your program exits.

Note that in this specific case, you don't even need to close the `os.File` since by default File has a `finalizer` to close itself when it is collected by the GC (see `newFile` function here: https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go).

Comment: Aah, silly me. Yes, I can confirm that moving defer out of init() solves the issue. But, I was wondering what's the best practice in this case without sharing filehandle `f` out of init() function to other functions (i.e. main()).

Comment: It depends on what the actual usage scenario is. It's pretty strange to have an `init()` in `main` - there's no reason not to just move that code into `main()` instead, which removes the problem altogether. If you're actually doing this in an `init()` in another package, then it becomes a more complex question, and the answer depends more on the specifics of the implementation.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I have init() in other package. I wrote this test program for simplicity and reproducing the issue.

Comment: You're probably abusing `init` functions. Most likely your solution would be to write a function in that package like `InitLogger` or something, and call that from `main()`. `InitLogger` can: return a function to `defer` that closes the file; return a `struct` with a `Close()` method you can `defer`; or the package itself can expose a `CloseLogger` function you can `defer`.

Comment: @Sarjeet: best approach depends on the scenario, but in this specific case you don't even need to share the file handler since the file will be closed anyway on program exit. I updated my answer to reflect that.